# Shell script to accept special characters from input

Tags: shell, sh

I have script that accepts passwords from user. As we know passwords can have special characters. So there is case when user have some specific characters the script I wrote does not work.

Have a look

```
./passwrd.sh sohan$23
sohan3
```

Here is script snippet

```
#!/bin/sh
#=============================================================================
#
# DESCRIPTION
#
# Script for creating csbuser in weblogic
#
# USAGE ./create.sh <password>
# where password is OPTIONAL.

if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
echo $1
#csb_password=`echo "$1" | sed -r 's/\$/\\\$/g'`
fi
```

Can anyone suggest me what can be done here.

Comment: Quotes! `./passwrd.sh 'sohan$23'`; `echo "$1"`

Comment: ...also, passing passwords on the command line is very, very bad security practice -- command lines are visible to all users on the system, so you're giving your passwords away to anyone who cares to log them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the script like `./passwrd.sh sohan$23`, the `$23` will be expanded.

To give it as a literal string, do use single quotes:

```
./passwrd.sh 'sohan$23'
```

#### EXample

```
$ cat a
#!/bin/bash

echo "the var is $1"

$ var=10
$ ./a a$var
the var is a10

$ ./a 'a$var'
the var is a$var
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. I need to update user instructions probably

Comment: Good to read that :) Consider accepting the answer if you are done.